# Nothing works - references, pointers

Tags: c

```
void load(int *n, int *x, int **arr)
{   
    arr = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*(*n));
    for(int i = *n; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0, x = 0;
    int *arr;

    load(&n, &x, &arr);

    printf("%d", arr[1]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The program compiles properly, but it throws windows error during the `printf()` in main function. Displaying just "arr" gives random big numbers. What is wrong here?

Comment: `arr` isn't an array. I'm not write sure what it is though... some sort of pointer to a pointer.

Comment: `arr = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*(*n));` - please don't cast `malloc` return values in C - it can hide certain subtle problems. Probably not this _specific_ problem but it will bite you one day :-)

Comment: Fundamental sanity check: When you're implementing reference semantics, you *must* have a `*` on the left-hand side of the assignment in the function body.

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean, could you provide some example?

Comment: `n` is zero, and so you allocate zero bytes of memory for `arr`, then scanf one int into it, and then read the memory for the second int in `arr`. That's at least 2 things wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*(*n));
```

doesn't change anything in main, it only overwrites the copy of the pointer (address of `arr` in `main`) that `load` receives.

What the function should do is change `arr` in `main`, for that, you have to dereference the argument,

```
*arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(*n)); // cast for C++ compiler left in
```

to change the value of `arr` in `main`. (The object that the argument `arr` of `load` points to, that is `arr` in `main`, needs to be changed, hence you need to modify `*arr` in `load`.)

The scans should then be

```
scanf("%d", &(*arr)[i]);
```

or (equivalent)

```
scanf("%d", *arr + i);
```

Comment: Hmm..printf("%d", arr) displays the first element. But arr[1], *arr+1, or *(arr+!), or any other number of course, still throws an error.

Comment: @user2251921 In `main`, you need `printf("%d\n", arr[i]);` (for `0 <= i < n`). `arr` is a pointer, so printing that with a `%d` conversion is undefined behaviour. You could use `*arr` instead of `arr[0]`, resp. generally, `*(arr + i)` for `arr[i]`.

Comment: @user2251921 But, in your example, you have `n = 0`, so you don't get any memory allocated (and there is an off-by-one in the scan loop, as noted by BLUEPIXY above).

Comment: @DanielFischer quick question. here `arr[i]` gives a `rvalue` and `*arr + i` gives an `lvalue reference`. am i right in thinking so?. i'm asking this because `&(*arr[i])` is should be same as `arr[i]` but differ as `lvalue` and `rvalue` resp.

Comment: @Koushik I suppose you're talking about `load` (doesn't help that the name `arr` refers to objects of different types)? Then `arr[i]` gives an lvalue of type `int*` (but it's undefined behaviour for `i != 0`), and `*arr + i` is an rvalue (`&(*arr)[i]`). `&(*arr[i])` is an rvalue with the same value as `arr[i]`, but note that I used `&(*arr)[i]` in `scanf`, which is different from `&(*arr[i])`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void load(int *n, int *x, int **arr)
{   
    int i = 0;
    *arr = (int*) malloc(*n * sizeof(int));
    if(!*arr) {
        perror("Can not allocate memory!");
        return;
    }
    for(i = *n; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        scanf("%d", *arr + i);
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0, x = 0;
    int *arr;
    int i;

    /* You probably need to initialize n */
    n = 5;
    load(&n, &x, &arr);

    for(i = n; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%d - %d\n", i, arr[i]);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why does scanf("%d", *arr + i) works, and scanf("%d", arr[i]) doesnt?

Comment: The type of `arr` is `int **`, that's mean `arr` will reference a memory address pointing to your data was allocated by `malloc`.
So, `arr[i]` will not reference your _i_ th entry, but will reference another memory location (which is basically a jump of _i_ address from `arr`). However, by using `*arr`, you are referencing your array data, adding `i` to that address you will reference to _i_ th element of your array. Hope it is clear :)